# update value with sum of multiple column

Tags: mysql

I have a table power, where I wan got the SUM of all my is_* fields and store it in the cnt column.

```
id | is_yellow | is_green | is_blue | cnt
1  | 1         | 1        | null    | -> 2
2  | null      | 1        | null    | -> 1
3  | 1         | 1        | 1       | -> 3
```

The query give "Invalid use of group function" back on Update:

```
UPDATE
  power
SET
cnt = (SUM(IFNULL(is_yellow, 0)) + 
  SUM(IFNULL(is_green, 0)) + 
  SUM(IFNULL(is_blue, 0)))
```

What's wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`COALESCE`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for this:

```
UPDATE
  power
SET
  cnt = COALESCE(is_yellow, 0) +
        COALESCE(is_green, 0) +
        COALESCE(is_blue, 0)
```

If the field is null, then `0` is used in the addition.